# Upper bound on $x^{T}Ay$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bilinear-form

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and let $d \times d$ matrix $A$ be symmetric and positive definite. We know that

$$x^{T}Ax \leq \lambda_{\max}(A) x^{T}x$$

where $\lambda_{\max} (A)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$. Similarly, can we say that $x^{T}Ay \leq \lambda_{\max}(A)x^{T}y$?

---

**Edit:** there was counter example. Now is there any constant $c$ such that $x^{T}Ay \leq c x^{T}y$?

Comment: You are basically asking whether $x^TPy$ is always nonnegative when $P$ is positive semidefinite. (In your case $P=\lambda_\max(A)I-A$.) The answer is clearly negative unless $P=0$: just pick a pair of $x$ and $y$ such that $x^TPy$ is nonzero. If $x^TPy<0$, you are done; otherwise replace $y$ by $-y$. For a concrete counterexample, consider $A=\operatorname{diag}(2,1)$ and $x=-y=(0,1)$.

Comment: @user1551 got it. now is there any other value $c$ s.t $x^{T}Ay \leq c x^{T}y$ holds ?

Comment: When $A$-orthogonality is not the same as orthogonality, then $x, y$ may be orthogonal while $x^T A y \neq 0$. The latter can be then chosen to be positive by e.g. negating $x$, if necessary.

Comment: @manifold You may apply Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz for $(x^\mathsf{T} Ay)^2$ to get a bound of other form.

Comment: Have you tried using a $2 \times 2$ block matrix?